# C# can't seem to correctly add images to ziparchive

Tags: c#, .net, io, zip, c#-ziparchive

I'm trying to add a bunch of files to a zipfile in c# but it doesn't seem to work properly.

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var zip = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < kaart_data.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            Image img = array[i];

            var file = zip.CreateEntry(i + ".bmp");
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                img.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                using (var entryStream = file.Open())
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(entryStream);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //saves the archive to disk
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\test.zip", FileMode.Create))
    {
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        memoryStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
}
```

The thing is it does create and save the zip file into disk with the expected file size.

But when I try to open them in windows photo viewer they seem to be corrupted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It almost took 3 hrs to figure out what's the issue. If u look at the the size of original image and extracted one, there's a tiny difference.

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var zip = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < images.Length; i++)
        {
            var img = images[i];
            var file = zip.CreateEntry(i + ".bmp");
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                img.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                using (var entryStream = file.Open())
                {// to keep it as image better to have it as bytes
                    var bytes = stream.ToArray();
                    entryStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"test.zip", FileMode.Create))
    {
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        memoryStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
}
```

I've tried it it works like a charm!

Comment: wow, not sure why turning the stream into a bytearray helps, but it totally works. thanks man!

Comment: What is the type of object is variable 'img'?

Comment: Image @SomeRandomDeveloper